# Автоматизация распределения затрат для планирования рекламной кампании

Tags: 1с, реклама, crm

Делаю дипломную работу, дошел до практиковой части. Нужно проработать автоматизированную систему распределения затрат под рекламу. Как это сделать и через что? В голову ничего не лезет. 0 знание 1с, да и CRM не очень хорошо разбираюсь. Есть у кого возможность помочь с этим?

Comment: Для начала необходима графическая схема КАК распределяются Затраты; Из этой схемы мы сможем понять какие исходные|выходные данные должны храниться в базе данных. Далее создаем Документ/Справочник для хранения этих данных; Создаем функционал - распределяющий затраты и формирующий выходные данные; И функционал - который делает проводки/движения по регистрам по Выходным данным; (это коротко, что нужно сделать)

Comment: Есть цены на рекламу, 9 видов рекламы. Интернет-реклама 915 000
Журналы 185 000
Наружная реклама 3 400 000
Справочные 88 000
Мероприятия для дизайнеров 735 000
Поздравление контрагентов с днем рождения 224 000
PR, благотворительные мероприятия 100 000
Кросс-маркетинг 255 000
Полиграфия 180 000
Вывески, ребрендинг 60 000
Радио 2 260 000

Comment: Создаем Справочник.ВидыРекламы (туда занесем 9 элементов) доп-реквизиты Сумма (15:2) и СтатьяЗатрат (пока текстовая строка) еще нужны Выходные данные (Что и как распределять ?)